# Rsyslog using more memory on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, unix, rsyslog

I see rsyslog is using more memory on my EC2 instance. Is there a way we can fix it?

I tried cat `/proc/<pid_of_rsyslogd>/limits` and tried changing the limit value but no luck.

Max stack size 8388608 unlimited bytes.

Answer (score 0):

/var directory was full Cleared it and restarted rsyslog service. That helped me fixing the problem.